# Measure Theory: Intersection of two Algebras on the same sample space

Tags: measure-theory

I have been stalled on the following question for a while now:

"Suppose $A$ and $B$ are algebras on the sample space $\Omega$. Prove that if $C = A \cap B$ then $C$ is an algebra on $\Omega.$"

I think I understand that this is true because the largest possible algebra is the set of all subsets and if we let $A$ be the largest possible algebra on $\Omega$ and let $B$ be an arbitrary algebra on $\Omega$ then $ A \cap B$ will always equal $B$ which is an algebra.

Since this topic is still new to me, any opinions improving or correcting my assumption would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You cannot prove a theorem by verifying it a special case. YOu cannot take  one of the algebras to be the power set.

Comment: Just prove it directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kavi Rama Murthy points out, you have only considered the special case of $A=\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$.
As you point out, this implies $A\cap B=B$ for any $B\subset\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$.
However, you still have to prove the case of $A\neq\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$!

**Hint**:
Let me get you started.
Suppose $A$ and $B$ are both algebras.
Let $C=A\cap B$.
To prove that $C$ is an algebra we have to check three things:

1. $\Omega$ is in $C$.
2. $C$ is closed under complements.
3. $C$ is closed under finite unions.

I'll prove (2) and let you prove the rest.
Let $c\in C$. Then, $c\in A$ and $c\in B$.
Since $A$ and $B$ are algebras (and hence closed under complement), it follows that $\Omega\setminus c\in A$ and $\Omega\setminus c\in B$.
Therefore, $\Omega\setminus c\in C$. That is, $C$ is closed under complements.

**Comment**: are you sure you did not mean $\sigma$-algebra? If you did, replace "finite unions" above by "countable unions". Otherwise, ignore this comment.